# ASP.Net Query string time out

Tags: asp.net, query-string

Is there a way to make an ASP.Net query string time out the way a session would time out? Is there any point in doing this? My superior seems to think that forcing a query string to time out, even though it is already encrypted, will improve security.

Answer (score 1):

You could try having the Session Id in the url.

`<sessionState cookieless="true" />`

Will have your application put the session id in each url. eg.
`http://yourserver/folder/(session ID here)/default.aspx` or `http://myapp/kfh73245y32fgdgfoe7tgdsofdgb8rt/profile.aspx?profileId=334`

Which means that url will only be valid with a session with that session id.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of and I don't see any point in doing this either.

A better way would be to use SSL since it encrypts the traffic including QueryString.